# Book involviing "the sword with the silver pommel" and a kiss to open the mind's eye

Tags: story-identification, books

A few years ago I was reading a book but it got lost and I want to continue reading it. I don't remember much and what I remember is probably very out of order and mixed with the second book of the series as well. I started to read the book because I had recently gotten a Kobo Arc 7 and the book was a featured book, this might help narrow the timeframe a bit.

In the book, the main character got a sword with a silver pommel which is a very important plot point and "the sword with the silver pommel" is mentioned over and over. Someone else in the book was trying to train the main character to fight early in the book. The main character burned incense to help him focus on some sort of work.

At some point a strange girl comes into the story and later on kisses the main character to open his mind's eye. The main character was kinda in love with her after that and assumed it was out of love but then she explains that she is with someone but needed to kiss him to open his mind's eye. With his mind's eye open he can see auras of things and magic stuff. I think he could see the auras with his eyes closed but I could be wrong. There were mythical creatures though I don't remember what creatures.

Comment: please put that answer in your question in a separate answer and accept it ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Per the [OP's update](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/205991/4), this is [*Sword Bearer*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15844217-sword-bearer) by [Teddy Jacobs](http://www.teddyjacobs.com/).

> Because the adventure is upon him, and it's an adventure full of
>   danger, full of blood, fire, demons and Evil. To face it, he'll need
>   the sword given him by his blademaster, need the ancient words his
>   grandfather bequeathed to him on his deathbed. Need the song that runs
>   in his own blood, in his veins.